# Express.js - Middleware - not executing next()

Tags: javascript, node.js, rest, express, middleware

I'm trying to execute a post function that has a next(); in the middle of the code, so i'm exporting the definition of the function from another file and trying to call it from express router. But it doesn't execute.

--EDIT

I've tried the regular definition as suggested above, but it stops when "next();" is called and returns

```
Cannot POST /registerUser
```

index.js

```
[...]
//Definição e Chamada de Componentes

   const userLogin = require('./userControl/accessControl');
   const userRegister = require('./userControl/registerControl');

[...]

var router = express.Router();              // get an instance of the express Router


//Definição das Rotas
//==============================================================================
router.post('/login', userLogin.login);
router.post('/forgotPassword', userLogin.forgotPassword);
router.post('/registerUser', function(req, res, next) {userRegister.registerUser});


app.use('/', router);

// START THE SERVER
// =============================================================================
app.set('env', 'production');
app.listen(port);
console.log('API Listening on Port ' +port+'');
```

registerControl.js

```
exports.registerUser = function(req, res, next) {

    var query = "INSERT INTO [user] (name, email, phone, login, password, enabled, profile) VALUES ('example', 'example@abc.si', 'XXXXXXXXXXXX', 'ADMIN', '12345', 1, 'TEST')


    global.conn.request()
        .query(query)
        .then(result => {
            var userId = result.recordset[0].id;
            console.log(userId);
            if (result.rowsAffected[0] == 0) {
                res.sendStatus(500);
            }
            else {
                req.body.userId = userId;
                next();
               }

        })
        .catch(err => res.json(err));

}, function(req, res) {
    var query = "INSERT INTO [user_company] (company_id, user_id) VALUES ("+req.body.companyId+", "+req.body.userId+");"

    global.conn.request()
    .query(query)
    .then(result => {

        if (result.rowsAffected[0] == 0) {
            res.sendStatus(500);
        }
        else {
            res.sendStatus(200);
        }
    })
    .catch(err => res.json(err));

};
```

Thanks!

Comment: You are not actually calling the middleware function. You need to actually execute the function with the arguments passed through or implicitly pass the handler. Imagine if you did `function(someArgument) { console.log }`, without the parenthesis after `log` it wouldn’t actually execute right?

Comment: Didn't understand @AlexanderStaroselsky.. How should I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

> `router.post('/registerUser', function(req, res, next)
>   {userRegister.registerUser});`

maybe try

> `router.post('/registerUser', userRegister.registerUser);`

Just like you did in the above `forgotPassword` route.

Comment: If I do that, the function goes well until 

```
req.body.userId = userId;
next();
```
Then it stops and returns "Cannot POST / registerUser to Postman

Comment: I think the problem is in the way you defined the second function ```firstFn() {
...
}, function(req, res) {}```

Instead, try creating the second function as an independent middleware and directly call that middleware on else condition in first function. i.e. ```else {
req.body.userId = userId;
newMiddleware();
}```